# Share environment variables from pipeline to downstream job

Tags: maven, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Maven projects in Jenkins, which download source code and then build, using `mvn clean install` and a pipeline that combines these two steps in a build stage.

The Jenkins maven plugin, expects to find an environment variable for the location of the maven repository. Namely, `${env.MAVEN_REPO}`.

My goal is to define this variable in the pipeline and so that downstream maven build jobs use it.
This is my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        MAVEN_REPO = "C:\\Users\\Chris\\development\\repositories\\maven"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo MAVEN_REPO
                echo env.MAVEN_REPO
                echo "${env.MAVEN_REPO}"
                build job: 'projectA'
                build job: 'projectB'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All three echo's above, print the already set value.
Now, in the downstream job, I have created "pre step > Execute Windows batch command", which contains:

```
echo MAVEN_REPO is %MAVEN_REPO%
echo List of variables:
SET
```

The problem is that `MAVEN_REPO` variable does not have a value.
Finally, printing all environment variables simply verifies that no `MAVEN_REPO` variable is defined.

I have even trying supplying the variable as job parameter, like so:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        MAVEN_REPO = "C:\\Users\\Chris\\development\\repositories\\maven"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo MAVEN_REPO
                echo env.MAVEN_REPO
                echo "${env.MAVEN_REPO}"
                build job: 'projectA', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'MAVEN_REPO', value: 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\development\\repositories\\maven']]
                build job: 'projectB'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but still the variable does not have a value when trying to print it using the downstream job's pre-step phase and running this bat command `echo MAVEN_REPO is %MAVEN_REPO%`.

Note: My Jenkins instance currently runs on Windows 10.

Comment: You could add the maven repo as a job parameter

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel You mean something like this `build job: 'projectA', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'MAVEN_REPO']]`. I've tried that and tried printing the variable through the pre-step phase of the downstream job, but still got nothing.

Comment: Yes I mean that. You forgot the `value` -> `name: 'MAVEN_REPO', value: 'MY_REPO'`

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I've also added the value as a string, but when running the downstream job pre-step phase I get "MAVEN_REPO is ".

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding a new section below with your current problem ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I've just edited my question adding the attempt with parameters. Even with this attempt, I cannot retrieve the variable's value from the downstream job.

Comment: I don't see the `value` in the `parameters` you give

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel: my bad, forgot to add it in the description, although I did test it with the value and still no luck. It should have been working like this, right?

Comment: Yes it should, have you added the parameter in the Job A too ?